# How to check and cast a type to Decodable in swift

Tags: ios, swift, decode

I want to make a networking request in which I could control the response is JSON raw value `[String: Any` or the `Decodable`.

Here is the example:

```
func reqest<T>(endpoint: EndPoint, completion: @escaping (Result<T, Error>) -> Void) {
   session.dataTask(with: request) { (data, response, error) in

       if T.self is Decodable.Type {
           try? JSONDecoder().decode(T.self, from: data)
       } else {
           try? JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: .mutableLeaves)
       }
   }.resume()
}
```

then when I want JSON value I just call with `T` as `[String: Any]` or just use any model confirm `Decodable` protocol.

The question is for this line:

```
try? JSONDecoder().decode(T.self, from: data)
```

How to cast `T` to `Decodable`?

I know to use:

```
func reqest<T: Decodable >(endpoint: EndPoint, completion: @escaping (Result<T, Error>) -> Void)
```

but `[String: Any]` isn't `Decodable`.

Or any better solution to achieve what I want? thanks.

Comment: `[String: Any]` doesn't conform to `Decodable`. I don't think you would be able to create a single method for both.

Comment: This kind of type check at runtime is pretty *unswifty*. Declare two methods with different constraints. And ignoring any error is very bad practice. And `.mutableLeaves` is pointless in Swift.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend to use overload for the `reqest(endpoint:completion:)` function to achieve what you want.

A structure that I would like for example is this:

```
enum ResponseError: Error {
    case noData
    case typeMismatch
}

func reqest<T>(endpoint: EndPoint, completion: @escaping (Result<T, Error>) -> Void) {
    baseReqest(endpoint: endpoint) { result in
        switch result {
        case .success(let data):
            do {
                guard let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data) as? T else {
                    completion(.failure(ResponseError.typeMismatch))
                    return
                }
                completion(.success(json))
            } catch {
                completion(.failure(error))
            }
        case .failure(let error):
            completion(.failure(error))
        }
    }
}

func reqest<T: Decodable>(endpoint: EndPoint, completion: @escaping (Result<T, Error>) -> Void) {
    baseReqest(endpoint: endpoint) { result in
        switch result {
        case .success(let data):
            do {
                let response = try JSONDecoder().decode(T.self, from: data)
                completion(.success(response))
            } catch {
                completion(.failure(error))
            }
        case .failure(let error):
            completion(.failure(error))
        }
    }
}

private func baseReqest(endpoint: EndPoint, completion: @escaping (Result<Data, Error>) -> Void) {
    session.dataTask(with: request) { (data, response, error) in
        if let error = error {
            completion(.failure(error))
            return
        }
        guard let data = data else {
            completion(.failure(ResponseError.noData))
            return
        }
        completion(.success(data))
    }.resume()
}
```

That way you can have generic response handling code in `baseReqest(endpoint:completion:)` function and separate only the response parsing in the other two functions.

Then calling `reqest(endpoint:completion:)` function could be

- using `[String: Any]` as response type:

```
reqest(endpoint: endpoint) { (result: Result<[String: Any], Error>) in
    // Handle result
}
```

- using `[[String: Any]]` as response type:

```
reqest(endpoint: endpoint) { (result: Result<[[String: Any]], Error>) in
    // Handle result
}
```

- and also using a `Decodable` object as response type:

```
struct Response: Decodable {}

reqest(endpoint: endpoint) { (result: Result<Response, Error>) in
    // Handle result
}
```

Comment: Yes, seems have to add one more method to achieve it.

Answer (score 0):

Do it in Swift way. Use the struct Codable (that gives you the Decodable together).

For example:

```
 struct testStruct: Codable {
   public var testString:String!
   public var testAny:Any!
   init(
          testString:String!,
          testAny:Any!
       )
   {
       self.testString = testString
       self.testAny = testAny
   }
```

Then you initialize it with this:

```
var testStructToUse:[testStruct] = []
```

From here you can populate it with append method:

```
testStructToUse.append(testStruct(testString: "any String", testAny: "any value"))
```

And encode with JSONencoder

```
let jsonData = try JSONEncoder().encode(testStruct)
```

Comment: Does the code above really work? `Any` shouldn't be Codable.